# App Store giftcard: How to remove plastic strip without making the code unreadable

Tags: mac-appstore

Often when I buy an App Store giftcard, as I remove the grey plastic strip covering the code number, the number itself tears and becomes unreadable. Removing it slowly doesn't seem to work any better than removing it quickly. There is a way to get a refund for an unreadable number, but it's a time-consuming process. (I'm in Taiwan, where bureaucratic rules are sometimes elaborate.)

There's no easy way to identify different batches of cards, so as to avoid those that seem more prone to doing this. But I'm wondering if there are any suggestions as to ways to prevent the paper from tearing in the first place. I can imagine that heating or cooling the whole card might change the way the glue on the strip interacts with the paper underneath. I don't want to experiment, lest I make matters worse.

Any ideas?

Edit: In this case I was able to guess the correct number on the third try, but at other times it's been too hard. I've added a picture here, since reader comments show they're not familiar with these particular cards: [image: Apple gift card damaged code number]

Comment: Are you taking care with which layer you work with? Given so many cards sold and so few questions about the problem…

Comment: Don't they just scratch off like a lottery card?

Comment: @SolarMike: There is no way to control which layer you work with — that's part of the problem. And I don't know how many questions are asked about the problem — the convenience store I have been buying the cards at for the past two years has a customer service line on which the agents are familiar with the problem.

Comment: @Tetsujin: No, they don't scratch off. Taiwan cards have a little strip of plastic glued on top of the code number. I've added a picture to the original post, to clarify.

Comment: Apple probably uses the same card everywhere and thatlooks like a scratch-off kayer - use a fingernail or a coin. Same system is used on lottery cards, bank pins etc.

Comment: No, it's definitely a strip of plastic — I've been using them here for two years. It's the same color as scratch-off, but it's tough plastic glued to the paper surface.

Comment: And they don't use the same card everywhere, because as you see this card is printed in traditional Chinese characters.